# Countable, infinite set intersecion

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R} $, $\mathbb{R}$ the real numbers. Show $r \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $(S+r) \cap S = \emptyset $, where $S+r :=[s+r:s \in S]$.

I'm confused on how this works, because surely the set $S$ incompasses the entire real numbers, so finding a real number to add onto any element of $S$ is impossible.

I was thinking about using the power set axiom on $S$, to create a larger set and then use an element from that set to get a result, but I don't think that will work.

Comment: Seems to be missing some conditions. Why is "countable" in the title? Did you mean to say that S is countable?

Comment: Sorry, yes, S is countably infinite.

Comment: If you edit your Q to correct it then the moderators might "un-hold" it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example $ S = [a, \infty) $ for some $ a \in \mathbb{R} $, and take any $ r \in \mathbb{R} $: it's easy to check that if $ r > 0 $ then $ S + r \subset S $, and if $ r < 0 $, then $ S \subset S + r $; in particular, the intersection is never empty

There *may* be some additional conditions to be imposed upon $ S $ to guarantee such an $ r $ exists, and in fact it seems the more interesting exercise